# How to set default values from a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I need to include a new column to my table, the column is not nullable, I want to set the default value from another table, is there possible?

I'm trying to do something like that:
`ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD NEW_COLUMN AS (SELECT ANOTHER_COLUMN FROM ANOTHER_TABLE WHERE MY_TABLE.FIELD1 = ANOTHER_TABLE.FIELD1)`
But I got an error:
Subqueries are not allowed in this context.

Comment: A `CONSTRAINT` cannot use a value from another *column*, let alone another table for its default value. This would need to be logic defined in your `INSERT` statement, which may well be within a stored procedure

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a computed column, which is different to me from a "default value." If I understand correctly and you want a computed column using a subquery, I suggest creating a view with the extra column. You can select/update the view instead of the table (and possibly only expose the view to other users). If you really want it to be a default value (where it starts off equal to your query, but can be changed to other values with `update`s), I think you should probably consider an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger.

Comment: You can't mix and match DDL and DML statements.

Comment: This sounds like a very unusual requirement, almost certainly your application logic should be providing this default value on insert, a default constraint cannot vary, its value must be scalar. Perhaps elaborate on your requirement.

Comment: "You can't mix and match DDL and DML statements." -- Funny comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of alter table , you can use Multiple table update statement to update a column value from a column in another table after defining joining condition!

```
UPDATE D
SET D.NEW_COLUMN = T.ANOTHER_COLUMN
FROM MY_TABLE D 
LEFT JOIN ANOTHER_TABLE T
   ON D.FIELD1 = T.FIELD1
WHERE (Use a condition optionally to just update those rows only in your column)
```